# How can I access my list in another form?

Tags: c#, list

I have a Staff and a Student class, the Student class is shown below.

```
public  class Student : Staff
{
    private int matriculationnumber;
    private  List<Student> studentlist = new List<Student>();
    public int Matriculationnumber
    {
        get
        {
            return matriculationnumber;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1000 || value > 9000)
            {
                //ADD VALIDATION 
            }

            else
            {
                matriculationnumber = value;
            }


        }
    }

    public List<Student> StudentList 
    {
        get { return studentlist; }
        set { studentlist = value; }
    }
}
```

I also have a GUI that allows the user to enter the details of a Student or Staff member which then add this to a list on the click of the add button shown below

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Student NewStudent = new Student();
    NewStudent.Name = txtName.Text;
    NewStudent.Address = txtAddress.Text;
    NewStudent.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    NewStudent.Matriculationnumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtPayMatNum.Text);
    List<Student> StudentList1 = NewStudent.StudentList;
    StudentList1.Add(NewStudent);

}
```

I want to know how I can access the data in this list in a different form?

```
public partial class StudentMenu : Window
{
    public StudentMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Want to be able to access the list information here?!
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: StudentMenu : Window ???

Comment: The basic question here should be if it is a good idea to store the student list inside a student object? Why not store it inside the main window or as static property on the student?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class in this way without List

```
public  class Student : Staff
{
    private int matriculationnumber;

    public int Matriculationnumber
    {
        get
        {
            return matriculationnumber;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1000 || value > 9000)
            {
                //ADD VALIDATION 
            }

            else
            {
                matriculationnumber = value;
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Can create a public static class with List container

```
public class StaticContext
{
      public static List<Student> studendList = new List<Student>();
}
```

When you create a Studend can add to your static List in memory:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Student NewStudent = new Student();
   NewStudent.Name = txtName.Text;
   NewStudent.Address = txtAddress.Text;
   NewStudent.Email = txtEmail.Text;
   NewStudent.Matriculationnumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtPayMatNum.Text);

   StaticContext.studendList.add(NewStudent);
}
```

In this way you can access to your list of students in each point of application

```
public partial class StudentMenu : Window
{
    public StudentMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Want to be able to access the list information here?!
        //Use here 
        foreach (Student s in StaticContext.studendList)
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving `studentlist` to somewhere else such that it is accesible from different forms, which would also help decoupling the model and the view; i.e. the problem could be solved with the introduction of an application state object or something similar.